# C/C++ сравнение указателей на разные объекты на равенство и отношение

Tags: c++, c, указатели, неопределённое-поведение

Уже который день пытаюсь разобраться, можно ли сравнивать указатели, относящиеся к разным объектам...

Проблема заключается в том, что в **Стандарте** эта тема обрисована крайне расплывчато.

Вот это *исследование* говорит, что сравнение указателей, относящихся к разным объектам, скорее **UB**, чем норма:

https://habr.com/company/pvs-studio/blog/418023/

Мои эксперименты показывают аналогичные результаты. В нескольких книгах по **C11/C++11** так же нашел упоминание о том, что сравнивать можно только указатели на один и тот же массив, плюс дополнительный элемент в конце массива.

Так же меня очень запутывает *хрестоматийное* соглашение о перегрузке оператора присваивания (copy/move):

```
T &operator=(const T &_t)
{
    if (this != &_t)// Получается, это неопределенное поведение?
    {
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Плюс, я в нескольких проектах (включая софт большого банка) видел сравнение указателей на разные объекты. Например, такое сравнение очень популярно в транзакциях, чтобы всегда блокировать (мьютексы) в одинаковой последовательности, исключая таким образом вероятность **deadlock**-а.

Мой вопрос:

Что конкретно (и по отдельности) говорят Стандарты **C** и **C++** о сравнении указателей на разные объекты? То, что написано в общедоступных черновиках, лично я понять не смог...

Comment: `видел сравнение указателей на разные объекты` я так понимаю они ещё на больше/меньше их сравнивали? Вот это уже точно UB. Сравнивать на больше/меньше можно только в массиве.

Comment: Да, сравнивали больше ли, и блокировали последовательно, начиная от младших адресов к старшим.

Comment: это UB. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086372/how-to-compare-pointers вот тут есть выдержка из стандарта (то что жирное) про сравнение на равно вроде можно.

Comment: `== !=` можно применять к любым указателям. `< <= > >=` только к указателям на элементы одного массива. Вместо последних есть `std::less/greater`, который работает с любыми указателями.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это абсолютно точная информация?) А то меня гложут сомнения.

Comment: @Максим, пожалуйста, не плодите метки типа ub/compare и прочие. У Вас достаточно репутации для этого, но это плохо для сайте. Метка должны помогать в поиске. compare в поиске никак не помогает. А вместо ub есть нормальная русскоязычная метка. Также укажите, что имеется ввиду сравнение на равенство, т.к. оно бывает разным.

Comment: @ixSci, хорошо, извините, я просто этого не знал.

Answer (score 4):

Денис Риччи: "Если р и q указывают на элементы одного массива, то к ним можно применять операторы отношения ==, !=, <, >= и т. д. Например, отношение вида
p < q
истинно, если р указывает на более ранний элемент массива, чем q. Любой указатель всегда можно сравнить на равенство и неравенство с нулем. А вот для указателей, не указывающих на элементы одного массива, результат арифметических операций или сравнений не определен."
Что касается этого примера:

```
T &operator=(const T &_t)
{
    if (this != &_t)// Получается, это неопределенное поведение?
    {
    }
    return *this;
}
```

здесь производится проверка, не написал ли кто-то в коде что-то типа а = а;.  В этом случае this и &_t будут указывать на один и тот же объект и (this != &_t) будет false.

Comment: Окей, а если в коде написано **a = b**, и объекты **a** и **b** не принадлежат одному массиву, то это неопределенное поведение?)

Comment: @Максим, если объекты **a** и **b** не принадлежат одному массиву, то указатели на них очевидно не равны друг другу, то есть **(a == b) -> false**. В этом  смысле поведение определено. Неопределённое поведение (или непредсказуемый результат) будет у операций <, >, <=, >=.

Comment: Меня все равно терзают сомнения...)

Comment: @Максим, пусть у нас два массива: mas1 и mas2. Располагаются они само собой в разных участках ОЗУ. Значит указатель на любой элемент mas1 не может быть равен указателю на любой элемент mas2. То есть: mas1[y] == mas2[x] всегда false, сравнение бессмысленно. mas1[y] < mas2[x] результат не определён - мы не знаем куда именно при выполнении скомпиллированного кода попадут эти массивы

Comment: А где это написано? В Стандарте какая-то непонятная каляка-маляка, которую даже разработчики статических анализаторов не могут однозначно истрактовать

Comment: Тут дело не только в положении в памяти. Указатель - абстракция, для которой возможно UB.

Comment: @Максим я знаю, что указатели в си - сложная тема, у меня тоже в голове крепко клинило при изучении ;) Да, указатель - это абстракция, но каждому указателю соответствует физический адрес в ОЗУ: &mas1[1] = 0X0A1234F например

Answer (score 1):

О каком именно типе "сравнения" идет речь?

- Сравнивать *на равенство/неравенство* можно любые указатели (при условии совместимости типов), независимо от того, указывают ли они в один массив или нет.

  В С++ не специфицируется результат сравнения на равенство двух указателей, если один из них указывает на воображаемый элемент за одним объектом, а второй указывает на другой объект.

  В С в такой ситуации говорится, что указатели будут равны, если указывают в одно и то же место в памяти.
- *Упорядочивающие* сравнения разрешается применять только к указателям на элементы одного массива или полям одного класса. (Правило рекурсивно распространяется на подобъекты этих объектов.)

  В остальных случаях: в С++ на результат сравнения не накладывается никаких требований. В С открытым текстом говорится, что поведение не определено.

Comment: **Сравнивать на равенство/неравенство можно любые указатели (при условии совместимости типов), независимо от того, указывают ли они в один массив или нет.** - где это написано? Ничего подобного в стандартах я не нашел.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в стандарте (6.5.9 (3)) четко сказано, что операторы **!=** и **==** аналогичны реляционным, за исключением приоритета. А значит, нельзя сравнивать указатели, которые не относятся к одному массиву, не важно, при помощи **>=** или **!=**.

Comment: @Максим: В стандарте С (6.5.9/3) написано, что они *аналогчины* реляционным, после чего сказано, в чем именно они аналогичны: возвращают 0 или 1. На этом аналогия заканчивается. Далее в 6.5.9/4 - 6.5.9/7 дается уже конкретное определение сравнений на равенство, где сказано все "не аналогичное". Описание поведения этих операторов с указателями дается в 6.5.9/6.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться с этим дальше, все как-то слишком запутано.

Answer (score 1):

На практике, для всех компов, на которых я писал на языке Си, можно приводить к `char *` (или преобразовывать в `size_t`) и сравнивать.

Imho  после приведения к `char *` на равенство можно сравнивать всегда (и это останется в обозримом будущем справедливо для всех архитектур).

Comment: Но и переполнение знаковых целых в большинстве случаев на современных платформах имеет строго определенное поведение, однако это не меняет того факта, что это **UB**, которое может все сломать в любой момент.

Comment: @Максим, ну что, кроме как *"в топку компайлеры с такими UB"*,  тут еще можно сказать?

Answer (score 0):

Если даже не обращаться к стандарту ( в стандарте все по логике...), просто рассуждать логически:  Что такое указатель?... Это место в памяти на одно машинное слово, где записывается адрес какого то обьекта или  нулевое значение(нулевой указатель).  Как можно сравнить эти адреса(что меньше, что больше?), по каким критериям?... Только если эти адреса совпадают или не совпадают, или нулевое или нет. А если   это в пределах какого то обьекта, где адреса идут один за другим (массив), то тогда можно и сравнить какой адрес раньше(меньше) другого... По моему так...