# Можно ли применять операции сравнения с указателями?

Tags: c

Можно ли применять операции сравнения к указателям в Си? Я так предполагаю, что да, но не понимаю для чего и в каких целях используется.

Comment: Например, чтобы выяснить, у какого элемента одного массива индекс меньше :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Разумеется можно.

Не совсем понятен вопрос "для чего", ибо операции сравнения применяются к указателям для точно тех же целей, для которых они применяются к любым другим типам. Сравнение значения указателя, например, со значением `NULL` - повсеместная и повседневная практика.

Далее [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/895839/182825):

- Сравнивать *на равенство/неравенство* можно любые указатели, при условии совместимости типов, независимо от того, указывают ли они в один массив или нет. Допускается сравнение указателей на данные с указателями `void *`.

  Язык гарантирует равенство указателей, если

  - Оба являются нулевыми указателями
  - Оба являются указателями на один и тот же объект или функцию. (Включая указатель на объект и указатель на первый подобъект этого объекта)
  - Оба являются указателями на один и тот же воображаемый элемент, располагающийся за последним элементом массива
  - Один является указателями на воображаемый элемент массива (располагающийся за последним элементом), а другой - на первый элемент следующего массива, непосредственно следующего за первым в памяти

  Разумеется, формирование значений указателей, участвующих в сравнении, должно было быть выполнено без неопределенного поведения.
- *Упорядочивающие* сравнения разрешается применять только к указателям на элементы одного массива (включая воображаемый элемент, располагающийся за последним элементом массива) или полям одного класса. В рамках этих требований, объекты, не являющиеся массивами, рассматриваются как массивы размера `1`.

  В остальных случаях поведение не определено.